# How can I target the canvas through the CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, spline

I was making a 3d website that uses a component made in Spline with ReactJS. I came across a problem that doesn't let me make the component responsive. When you inspect the code, I noticed that a canvas tag was generated by spline. How can I target that canvas element with CSS so that I can make it responsive. Here is the code I am using:

```
const Header = () => (
  <div className="wrapper">
                 <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                <Spline className="spline" canvasClassName='canvas'  scene="https://prod.spline.design/mBHAychRuVpOVVWU/scene.splinecode"/>
                </Suspense>
                <div className="text-div">
                  <h5 className="head-text">We <span className='typed-text'><Typed
                      strings={[
                        'design to inspire.',
                        'build to capture.'
                      ]}
                      typeSpeed={120}
                      backDelay={160}
                      loop/></span></h5>
                </div> 
  </div>
);
```

Here was the inspected code looks like

[image]

I tried styling the parent div. However everytime I try to do that the aspect ratio of my canvas changes, making the height longer than the width which makes some of the content disappear

Comment: Nope, I left out the 3d design and just opted for a different one. Might get back to trying to solve it eventually as I am very busy now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that help me to minimize or adjust the size of element ( canvas ) inside the Spline

```
<div className="mb-40 w-full h-2/4 md:h-[425px] md:w-[538px] relative border border-red-600 ">
      <Spline style={{width:"150%", height:"160%"}} className="scale-[.5] absolute -top-1/4 -left-1/4"  scene="https://prod.spline.design/UWoeqiir20o49Dah/scene.splinecode"/>
</div>
```

change the **scale** value to minimize and maximize the design like **scale-[.25]** to decrease the size ..